# Back to Coq proof checker after 5-8 years away: how to prove that (forall n, m : N, (n - (S m)) = pred(n - m))?

Tags: coq

Somewhere between 5 and 8 years ago (probably 6 or 7) I wrote a full Formalization of Bubble Sort in Coq. One of the earliest Lemmas proven was the one in the title, which I called "sub_succ_r" (or maybe it's the standard name?):

```
forall n m : nat, (n - (S m))%nat = pred(n - m)
```

Now, back then, this was the very simple proof for that Lemma:

```
intros n m.
induction n m using n_double_ind.
simpl.
auto.
apply sub_0_r.
Qed.
```

"sub_0_r" is the Lemma that asserts that

```
forall n : nat, (n - 0)%nat = n
```

Now, attentive readers who are also familiar with modern Coq might have already spotted the problem with the old proof: that second line.

```
induction n m
```

i.e. simultaneous induction on 2 terms, doesn't work any more, not even when specifying that one is using "n_double_ind".
I've been wracking my head over how to prove this using first induction over n and then induction over m, but I just can't figure it out.

Any help, great or small, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply induction on two variables simultaneously, you need to use comma separator, or Coq recognizes `f t` as `f` applied to `t`, so when you write `n m` this actually means `n` is a function and you want to apply it to `m`. Instead, use comma like this:

```
induction n, m.
```

this generates four subgoals. Two of them can be proved using auto so you can ask Coq to use auto tactic on every subgoal generated by induction, using semicolon like this:

```
induction n, m; auto.
```

and the remaining subgoals are easy to prove using the lemma you mentioned and induction hypotheses. so the whole script is as follows:

```
Lemma sub_0_r : forall n : nat, (n - 0) = n.
Admitted.

Theorem sub_succ_r: forall n m : nat, (n - (S m)) = pred(n - m).
Proof.
  induction n, m; auto.
  - apply sub_0_r.
  - apply IHn.
Qed.
```

Also note that using `%nat` is not necessary.

But as you saw we only used `IHn` which means that we didn't use the induction hypothesis for `m`, so we do not need to use `induction` on m, only a `destruct` tactic would do the job, a better proof is:

```
induction n; destruct m; auto.
- apply sub_0_r.
- apply IHn.
```

which is minimal and elegant.

Comment: This does help, thanks. However, after the `apply sub_0_r`, I am left with the Induction Hypothesis `IHn: (n - S (S m)) = pred (n - S(m))` and the goal `S n - S (S m) = pred(S n - S m)`. Simply applying IHn isn't enough, as CoqIde (quite rightly, I suspect) gives an error when I try this. So I have to rework the goal to resemble the Induction Hypothesis, or vice versa. This is probably really obvious and I'm missing it only due to being rusty as all hell, but I just can't seem to figure out how to go from here.

Comment: For me, the proof script I provided completely does the job, using CoqIde 8.11.0. maybe you're missing some silly detail?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added a "intros n m" before the induction as was in the original proof from 8 years ago. This adds 2 extra "S"s to the Induction Hypothesis, making it `IHn: (n - S (S m)) = pred(n - (S m))`. Leaving out the intros makes the Induction Hypothesis be `IHn: forall m: nat, (n - S m) = (n - m)`. I suspect this allowed the proof checker to just add an 'S' to everything in the Induction Hypothesis. And maybe the `forall m: nat` helped too, IDK.

Comment: Anyway, it's working now. My sincere and deepest gratitude for your help. I would have been completely stuck without it.

Comment: @AhsimNreiziev <3